# Exercise: Calculating Q-value for $D_0 \to \chi_s^-e^+\nu_e$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, scattering-cross-section, particle-detectors

### Question

Is the following methodology correct in calculating the Q-value (change in kinetic energy) for the $D^0 \to \chi_s^-e^+\nu_e$ decay process?

> **Steps**
>
> 1. The change in kinetic energy is $Q = (m_f - m_i)$ where masses are in $\text{MeV}/c^2$ and hence, as $m_{\nu_i} \approx 0$,
>      $$
>    \tag{1}
>    Q = m_{\chi_s^-} + m_e - m_{D^0}
>    $$
> 2. I look to find $m_{D^0}$ and in analogy to (A1) I take,
>      $$
>    \tag{2}
>    \Gamma_{D^0} = \frac{G_F^2m_{D^0}^5}{192\pi^3} = \frac{1}{\tau_{D^0}}
>    $$
>      and solving for $m^5_{D^0}$ gives,
>      $$
>    \tag{3}
>    m^5_{D^0} = \frac{192\pi^3}{\tau_{D^0}}\frac{1}{G^2_F}
>    $$
> 3. I can use (A1) to obtain a value for $G^{-2}_F$ as, 
>      $$
>    \tag{4}
>    \frac{1}{G^2_F} = \frac{m^5_\mu\tau_\mu}{192\pi^3}
>    $$
>      where I used the fact that $\Gamma_\mu = 1/ \tau_\mu$
> 4. I can then insert (3) into (4) to solve for $m_{D^0}$ as,
>      $$
>    \tag{5}
>    m_{D^0} = 
>    \left(
>        \frac{192\pi^3}{\tau_{D^0}}
>        \frac{m^5_\mu\tau_\mu}{192\pi^3}
>    \right)^{\frac{1}{5}}
>    =
>    m_\mu
>    \left(
>        \frac{\tau_\mu}{\tau_{D^0}}
>    \right)^{\frac{1}{5}}
>    $$
> 5. Inserting values for (5),
>      $$
>    m_{D^0}
>    =
>    105.7\ \text{MeV}/c^2
>    \left(
>        \frac{2.197 \times 10^{-6}}{410 \times 10^{-15}}
>    \right)^{\frac{1}{5}}
>    =
>    105.7
>    \left(
>        5.359 \times 10^{6}
>    \right)^{\frac{1}{5}}
>    \ \text{MeV}/c^2
>    \\
>    = 2343.6\ \text{MeV}/c^2
>    $$
>      The rest is fairly straightforward if $m_{D^0}$ is correct.

### Issue

The $D^0$ rest mass, $m_{D^0}$ I am obtaining in my working,

$$m_{D^0} = 2344\ \text{MeV/}c^2$$
does not correlate with the known rest mass [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_meson#cite_note-PDGD0-6) of,

$$m_{D^0} = 1,864.84 ± 0.17\ \text{MeV/}c^2$$

### Prior Knowledge

I am asked to calculate the Q-value of this decay given that the *total decay rate* of a $\mu^-$ decay is,

$$
\tag{A1}
\Gamma_\mu = \frac{G_F^2m_\mu^5}{192\pi^3}
$$

where $G_F$ is the Fermi coupling and $m_\mu$ is mass muon.
I am aware that the branching ratio, $\text{Br}(\mu^- \to e^-\bar{\nu}_e \nu_\mu) = 1$ so for this specific $\mu^- \to e^-\bar{\nu}_e \nu_\mu$ process,

$$
\tag{A2}
\Gamma(\mu^- \to e^-\bar{\nu}_e \nu_\mu) = \Gamma_\mu\text{Br}(\mu^- \to e^-\bar{\nu}_e \nu_\mu) = \Gamma_{\mu}
$$

I am given the following,
$$
\tag{A3}
m_\mu = 105.7\ \text{MeV}/c^2\\
m_{\chi_s^-} = 494\ \text{MeV}/c^2\\
m_e = 0.511\ \text{MeV}/c^2\\
\tau_{\mu} = 2.197\ \mu \text{s}\\
\tau_{D^0} = 410\ \text{fs}\\
\text{Br}(D^0 \to \chi_s^-e^+\nu_e) = 0.065
$$

### Question Information

The question is given as,

> The $D^0$ meson has quark content $c\bar{u}$ andd lifetime, $\tau_{D^0} = 410 \text{fs}$. It decays as $D^0 \to \chi_s^- e^+ \nu_e$ with a branching ratio of 6.5%, where $\chi^−_s$ is an $s\bar{u}$ meson.
>
> Assuming that the mass of the $X_s^−$ state is 494 MeV, calculate the Q-value of this decay (the amount of kinetic energy released).

Comment: Ugh... 5 hours of effort and I realise only now that I post the question that a formula sheet was also provided with the exam containing $m_{D^0} = 1865\ \text{MeV}$ ... *c'est la vie*. Either way I am still confused why the above working doesn't give me $1865\ \text{MeV}$!

Comment: Wrong sign in the defn of Q on the first line in 1. ?

Comment: I'm defining $Q$ as the change in k.e. so unless the overall sign is different ($Q\to -Q$)? It doesn't actually affect the calculation of $m_{D^0}$ as am just using $Q$ to motivate why I want to find the mass $m_{D^0}$

Comment: Yes, the kinetic energy released is *positive* not negative. You also calculated the *total* width of the *D0*, not the width of this decay. So you never used the tiny B.R. provided... (Remember the *χ* masquerades as the muon neutrino in this far-fetched analogy...). But a lot more variables enter in this semileptonic decay, including *Q*...

Comment: Thanks, that really helps and ties into a comment in the exam feedback about using $Q$ in a later part. If I wanted to calculate $m_{D^0}$ in this way, I guess, not only would I need $Q$ to account for lost k.e. but I would also a CKM element and a branching ratio. Definitely gives me something to progress forwards with though. w.r.t. the negative sign difference, I think I'm a fermion, I tend to anti-commute a lot when swapping between lines